# Spotfire 3D plot

Tags: colors, 3d, expression, spotfire

I plotted a 3D wellbore using surveys. I would like to color the horizontal sections of the wellbore based on certain fracture depths. I have two additional columns that have these fracture depths. Is there a way to use custom expression to color my 3d wellbore using these two columns, for example: if([measured.depth]>[upper.perf] and ([measured.depth]<[lower.perf])), then color Axis.measured.depth(blue). Hope that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: yes there is a way. please add more information so a more detailed answer can be given.

Comment: @niko hey, I just uploaded a picture with the column names, and an idea of what I'm trying to color. Thanks

Comment: this doesn't really provide any new information, but rereading your question I think I see what you're trying to ask. lemme take a whack. you could further clarify by providing stuff like: what kind of chart are you trying to use, what is your coloring criteria, etc.

Comment: @niko, apologies. I wasn't sure what sort you info you needed, but I'm trying to use a 3D scatter plot where the coloring criteria is based on two columns (upper perf and lower perf). Lets say, for Perf #1, the coloring criteria would color any measured depth value in between the upper and lower perf value in green. Each perf will be highlighted in a color on top of the actual 3d plot. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

probably the most straightforward and "correct" way to do this is to create a new **Calculated Column** (Insert » Calculated Column). here you can build an expression that will be used later to define colors. based on the info you provided, that expression could look like:

```
If([Measured Depth (ft)] > [Frac Lower Perf] AND [Measured Depth (ft)] < [Frac Upper Perf])
```

this will return `True` for values outside of `[Frac Upper Perf]` and `[Frac 
Lower Perf]` and `False` otherwise. you can make these labels a bit more informational ("Inside"/"Outside" maybe?) by modifying the `If()` statement (see the documentation for details)

if you open up the visualization properties, then go to the **Colors** page, you have options for the Color By **Columns**. choose the column we just created. change the **Color Mode** to *Unique Values* and choose your color for the true and false values.

Comment: also, this is maybe a little more of a personal opinion than fact, but 3D charts are usually not necessary and more distracting than informational. do you trust your users to be able to use the view navigation controls? if not, are you going to print the chart? how will the depth dimension be perceived if so? I suppose they look cool, but that third dimension detracts from the understanding of the data. I strongly recommend dropping it. $.02 :)

Comment: I will try to create a calculated column and color by the new column. And I definitely understand where you're coming from on a 3d plot not being too helpful to visualize. I'm not going to print it, I just wanted to visualize a huge set of wells nearby and thought maybe trying out 3d would be cool. Again, just wanted to try and see how it works out, if it doesn't look too good, will definitely drop the idea. Thanks for the help niko!