# Spotfire Directional Survey 3D plot tutorial

Tags: plot, 3d, spotfire

How can I get in touch with the person who made this post --> [Spotfire 3D plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258920/spotfire-3d-plot) ??? I am looking for a tutorial on how to do what he did and on how he implemented what he was asking in the post

Comment: please use (at the rate) symbol and type his name, he will get your message

Comment: something like this? @ron

Comment: Yes you can send the same